# Multiple images in a single entry- Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-data

I am creating a Core Data application in Swift. It's a Diary like app where user can enter an entry with a title field and an image picker. Right now, I have only 1 image Attribute with type Binary Data. What I want is for user to be able to pick more than 1 image per entry. How can I link multiple images with 1 entry?

Comment: saving image in coredata as binary is not a good idea. you should try to save it to disk and insert the filepath as an attribute. also to answer your main question. you should have another entry called images and you have to set 1-n relation between your diary entry and image entries.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: @SonicMaster At that time I went with 3 image data fields in the same core data entity. But later on, I learned How to use a different entity for images and making a relationship with main entity. I created another app with this relationship logic.

Comment: So basically you create two entity (main entity and image entity)? In main entity you create field Images that has relationship to your image entity?

Comment: In main entity, you can create a key, say a timestamp and in image entity, you can create a binary field attribute or a image path attribute plus another attribute which can be an id, when saving the document/entity, make sure that main entity's key and all the keys/ids of image entity have same value. So, you can access all images for a particular entity by filtering id of that particular value. This way, you won't need to create relationship model. This is a simpler way.

Comment: Or you can create a relationship inverse model. You can learn that here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-25070

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an additional Entity, for example with the name "images".
2. Connect them through Interface Editor (into both directions) entry <> images
3. Create the NSManagedClasses (or update them)

Now you are able to set images for every entry. With:

```
let entry = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("entry", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! YourModel (Entry)

//When you now save an image, just do:

let image = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("myImage", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! MyImage
entry.myImage = image // this will "connect" your image with your main NSManagedObject
```

class example:

```
class Entry: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var myImage: [MyImage]?
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But, what is [MyImage] ? Shouldn't it be [NSData] ?

Comment: MyImage is an NSManagedObject. So it is 1 row in an sql table (easy spoken) - a row could contain multiple columns (that are object properties) -> if you need ony 1 field (containing NSData) create an NSManagedObject with 1 property called "data" (for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will let you know tomorrow if it works.

Comment: There are hundreds of CoreData Tutorials on the web. I would try some of them first, to find out how CoreData works. If you have any specific question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. As, I have never worked with multiple entities, so, a question: I do need to add a "relationship", right? In "Entry" entity: rel. with name "images", Destination: "Images", Inverse: "images"; then in "Images" entity:, rel. with Name: "entry", Des.: "Entry", Inverse: "entry". Right?

Comment: Yes. But check out that the direction from entry->images is "One to Many"

Comment: I have set Type to "To Many" in both of the relationships. In which case it is necessary. The one defined in "Entry" entity(named "images") or in "Images" entity(named "entry")?

Comment: Only from entry to images. One entry could have multiple images. But every image just got 1 "entry".

Comment: So, entry Entity to images Entity, right? Also, in "Entry+CoreDataProperties.swift" file, I am getting this: @NSManaged var images: NSSet? ; not like you wrote- [Images].

Comment: You can change that in your file. Default its always an NSSet, but i would prefer to change it to [myImage] for example.

Comment: NSSet? willl work too? Plus, is [myImage] our own defined or should it be [Images]?

Comment: It should be your "Images" NSManagedObject Class. Please try to find an tutorial for CoreData - there are hundreds. These are easy questions. Otherwise we should continue in chat.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I will check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108253/discussion-between-karanveer-singh-and-derdida).